# How to set the form into the window in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am a new in **extjs** and I prepared one login form.

I used that form into the `Ext.window.Window` but when it display on browser its showing separately

```
var win = new Ext.window.Window({
       renderTo: Ext.get('main'),
       items: form,
});
win.show();
```

Comment: Don't render you window to something. Windows are floating component, they render as absolute elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var win = new Ext.window.Window({
       renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
       items: form,
});
win.show();
```

Comment: Actually i created one div in <body> where i am using one css whose name is "main" so wanted to reder with that only.in your case if i userenderTo: Ext.getBody() then it display after the div.here i am posting my html<style> 
       #main{ 
       margin:auto; 
        width:300px;  
        height:680px;  
       margin-left: 390; 
       
      } 
     </style> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="main">
 
</div></body>

Comment: Doesn't really matter because the Ext.window.Window is not DOM code that will be contained within any div container. It's a floating element that appears when you call its `show()` method. It behaves just like a regular app window. So if I understand correctly you want something that looks like a Window but that can be placed within your #main div? You need to use an Ext.panel.Panel instead